# How does maven default life cycle get executed on maven project

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have this very simple question in the context of maven. In the maven world, it says everything about my project is defined in the project object model.

So, when I put `<packaging>` element inside my project object model to be  war etc, then maven will apply appropriate goals to default life cycle of maven.But to make it work, I have to define the project maven-war-plugin inside the build section of my project object model. But when I inspect my pom and super pom, it does not have maven-war-plugin included. I am using maven 3.0.5 and super pom is located inside

```
\maven-model-builder-3.0.5\org\apache\maven\model
```

following is the content of the super pom. So I'am confused here from where does it take this plugin if it is not described in the project object model. definition of pom says that everything about my project is defined inside the project object model. Could anybody help me here to understand the concept clearly. Thanks in advance for any help

```
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<!-- START SNIPPET: superpom -->
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <pluginManagement>
      <!-- NOTE: These plugins will be removed from future versions of the super POM -->
      <!-- They are kept for the moment as they are very unlikely to conflict with lifecycle mappings (MNG-4453) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>

  <profiles>
    <!-- NOTE: The release profile will be removed from future versions of the super POM -->
    <profile>
      <id>release-profile</id>

      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>performRelease</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation>

      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
<!-- END SNIPPET: superpom -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`default-bindings.xml`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/4ec06bf67cc6bdffa026f46c5836e3bc895865ed/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml), particularly the definition for [`<role-hint>war</role-hint>`](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/4ec06bf67cc6bdffa026f46c5836e3bc895865ed/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml#L235):

```
<component>
  <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping</role>
  <role-hint>war</role-hint>
  <implementation>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping</implementation>
  <configuration>
  ...
          <package>
            org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war
          </package>
```

This defines what goal will be run for this packaging type's `package` phase by reference to the war-specific plugin.

This is covered by the [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) in [Built-in Lifecycle Bindings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have another question, When i look at super POM, i can not see, maven-archetype-webapp plugin, but when i look at effective pom, I can see this plugin in the build section. How does it get included into the effective pom if it is not in the supper pom or child pom

Comment: If it's there it's being brought in by the pom itself, a parent pom, the super pom or a packaging definition. You might try modifying your pom and running `effective-pom` again to see what changes and what's bringing it in.

Comment: I was thinking pom is created by parent pom, supper pom and pom it self, based on your answer, it can be created by the packaging i select. is that correct. But i didn't find this point in the documentation